# Hard Disk Un-used space

Tags: virtualization, hard-drive, partition, disk-image

I have a hard drive of 150gb. I recently cloned a vmdk as physical onto this hard disk. My question is, because the vmdk was 90gb of partition space, the rest of my 150gb space is not shown as a partition. Do anyone know how to recover the rest of the space as partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fdisk` or some other partition editor of your choice and add some new partitions.  It may also be possible to resize your existing partitions (and the resident filesystems).  You can use `parted` to resize partitions.  If you've got an ext2/3 filesystem on it, you can use `resize2fs` to resize the filesystem after you've resized the partition.